# attachments from Mailgun to kindle

Tags: mailgun, kindle

I tried to send a self generated mobi file to kindle through mailgun. I tried lots of times, below are the logs for the message status

`"delivery-status": {
    "tls": false,
    "mx-host": "",
    "code": 499,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 80.14214205741882,
    "retry-seconds": 600,
    "message": "Unable to connect to MX servers: [retail-smtp-in.amazon.com]",
    "certificate-verified": false
  },`

I don't know why it shows unable to connect to MX servers. I guess it's amazon side problem cause when I send file to gmail account, it did succeed.

PS: I did set up my email address in the amazon setting.

Comment: I don't know what's happening in details, but after a lot of trials, it works fro 2-3 times when I pushed the items. But mostly, it works for gmail. Would anyone explain what is happening and how to make the best configuration?